# Rendering Haml file in a javascript response with rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I am trying to render a haml file in a javascript response like so:

```
$('#<%= @email.unique_name %> .preview .mail_content').html('<%=j render( :file => "user_mailer/#{@email.key}") %>');
```

An example of the file that would render is:

```
- variables = { :contact_first_name => @contact.first_name, :user_full_name => @user.name, :user_first_name => @user.first_name }

= @email.intro_html(variables)

%p= "Please click the link below to go directly to the results of #{@user.first_name}'s assessment. You can also access an analysis of that assessment from that page."

%p= share_results_url(@token)

= @email.conclusion_html(variables)
```

Now two problems occur for me if we look at the javascript that is given in the response:

```
$('#launch_share_results .preview .mail_content').html('\u003Cp\u003EHi Jane,\u003C/p\u003E
\u003Cp\u003EJohn Smith has taken a 360(deg) \u003Cspan style=color:red;\u003E\u003Cstrong\u003ENo such variable available!\u003C/strong\u003E\u003C/span\u003E assessment through myLAUNCHtools.com and would like to share the results with you.\u003C/p\u003E
\u003Cp\u003EPlease click the link below to go directly to the results of John's assessment. You can also access an analysis of that assessment from that page.\u003C/p\u003E
\u003Cp\u003Ehttp://lvh.me:3000/assessments/results/1\u003C/p\u003E
\u003Cp\u003EThank you in advance for your time and interest in John\u0026#8217;s leadership.\u003C/p\u003E
\u003Cp\u003ESincerely,\u003Cbr /\u003E
Launch\u003C/p\u003E
');
```

The major problem is that the response has newlines in it. This breaks the request. I presumed using j in front of my render call would fix that, but it doesn't.

The other problem is that on the third line of the haml file I have:

```
#{@user.first_name}'s assessment
```

and that apostrophe also breaks the request. (I know this because I used a javascript function to delete all the new lines and the request was still broken until I took out that apostrophe as well)

Is there a simpler way to clean up the javascript response than chaining on javascript functions to clean it up for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced a similar problem. Problem exists because both methods, 'escape_javascript' and 'json_escape' are aliased as 'j' (https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/3578).

Solution:
Use 'escape_javascript' instead of 'j'.